# How to get access to Google Analytics Real Time Reporting API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I filled the Real Time Reporting API Private Beta request access form many days ago but it seems that I can't access the API.

I sent a request to  https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime but I get the following response:

```
    {
        "error": {
            "code": 403,
            "message": "Requests to this API analytics method analytics.gaapi.v3.AnalyticsDataRealtime.Get are blocked.",
            "errors": [
                {
                    "message": "Requests to this API analytics method analytics.gaapi.v3.AnalyticsDataRealtime.Get are blocked.",
                    "domain": "usageLimits",
                    "reason": "rateLimitExceeded"
                }
            ],
            "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
        }
    }
```

I know that my access token and credentials are correct because I can get sessions data successfully but I can't use the realtime API. What can I do to be whitelisted by google?

Comment: Read the response better. `rateLimitExceeded`. You have passed the number of request you can make.

Answer (score 0):

**rateLimitExceeded** indicates that the project queries per 100 seconds rate limits have been exceeded.

*Recommended Action*: Retry using exponential back-off. You need to slow down the rate at which you are sending the requests.

Documentation here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/errors

Comment: Thank you for your help. I made one request only so it is really strange that I exceeded the rate limit